# Error al añadir Firebase a mi app android

Tags: android, firebase

Al añadir el fichero .json de Firebase y ejecutar la app me dice que no encuentra el paquete (me sale el último duplicado (com.sgm.xxxx.xxxx). He añadido el fichero correctamente y seguido todos los pasos, pero dentro de ese paquete existen varios sub-paquetes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todos están metidos dentro de com.sgm.xxxx, a su vez contiene otros paquetes.
como debo de hacer esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que muestras en tu imagen indica que tienes la vista "Android" configurada en Android Studio y el paquete de tu aplicación debe ser el que señalo en el rectangulo rojo.

Esta estructura de directorios debe existir fisicamente y es el package name que debes definir en Firebase.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias Jorge. Leyendo en una de tus muchas respuestas, he consultado mi fichero build.gradle y he observado que el paquete no era el que puse en Firebase. Ya lo he corregido. Hice una modificación del nombre de los paquetes que no tuve en cuenta.  Gracias como siempre por estar ahí.